# How to deploy an application to cloud run in google cloud?

Tags: image, docker, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry, docker-entrypoint

I created a docker image by Dockerfile

```
    FROM golang:1.15-buster as builder
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY . .
    COPY ../../../common/library/golang /app
    
    RUN go build -o server
    
    FROM debian:buster-slim
    RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        ca-certificates && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
    COPY --from=builder /app/server /server
    
    CMD ["/server"]
```

Build it with docker build in local

```
    $ docker build -t asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service .
```

Push it to google container registry

```
    $ docker push asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service
```

Deploy it to cloud run by command

```
    $ gcloud run deploy my-service --image asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service

    Please choose a target platform:
     [1] Cloud Run (fully managed)
     [2] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on Google Cloud
     [3] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on VMware
     [4] cancel
    Please enter your numeric choice:  1
    
    To specify the platform yourself, pass `--platform managed`. Or, to make this the default target platform, run `gcloud config set run/platform managed`.
    
    Allow unauthenticated invocations to [my-service] (y/N)?  N
    
    Deploying container to Cloud Run service [my-service] in project [my-project] region [asia-northeast1]
    ⠹ Deploying new service... Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service@sha256:
    23e3e62e4a2d9c5fb098d01a1e9eb85872c552dd31701ba8525fce692f924d50"
    error: "Command \"/server\": invalid
     mode \"-rw-r--r--\" for /server"
    X Deploying new service... Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service@sha256:
    23e3e62e4a2d9c5fb098d01a1e9eb85872c552dd31701ba8525fce692f924d50"
    error: "Command \"/server\": invalid52dd31701ba8525fce692f924d50"
     mode \"-rw-r--r--\" for /server"
    ]. mode \"-rw-r--r--\" for /server"
    ].
      . Routing traffic...
    
    
    Deployment failed
    ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service@sha256:23e3e62e4a2d9c5fb098d01a1e9eb85872c552dd31701ba8525fce692f924d50"
    error: "Command \"/server\": invalid mode \"-rw-r--r--\" for /server"
].
```

Why it's `Invalid ENTRYPOINT`? Is it necessary to change mode of execute file? Or other reason?

Comment: No, it's not normal. Can you run locally your container with `docker run` command? I always use the `go build` command with `-v` param. I don't know if it can change anything!

Comment: I tested without the -v, no change, it works. But I build with Cloud Build and not locally. Do you have old image locally and you use incorrect ones? Can you try to build on Cloud Build also? Use this command `gcloud builds submit --tag asia.gcr.io/my-project/my-service`

Comment: I used cloud build got the same result. The reason was my Dockerfile, I called an another path so it can't find the files: `COPY ../../../common/library/golang /app`.